# If $A^iB_i$ is called a contraction, what is $A^{ij}B_{ij}$ called?

Tags: reference-request, tensors, geometric-algebras

I have a tensor $A^{ijk}$ and a tensor $B_{ijk}$, and I'd like to contract all the indices between them, resulting in the scalar $k$:

$$k = A^{ijk}B_{ijk}$$

Is there a name for this sort of "multi-contraction"?

By knowing the name, I'd like to study this type of operation more.  I'm not sure whether they occur in the study of differential forms, or tensor algebra, or geometric algebra, or otherwise.

Comment: I believe this one is also called just contraction.

Comment: lisyarus is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They occur in many places. An example is the scalar curvature

$$
S = g^{ij}R_{ij}
$$

where $g^{ij}$ is the metric tensor and $R^{ij}$ the Ricci curvature, which in turn is also the contraction of the Riemann curvature tensor

Comment: Some authors also use the term "trace" or "metric trace" in your example.  I personally use contraction when dealing with the operation on mixed tensors, e.g., Ricci curvature is the contraction of the Riemannian curvature, $R_{ij}=R_{kij}^{\,\,\,k}$; and trace to indicate metric dependence, e.g., scalar curvature is the trace of the Ricci curvature, $S=\text{tr}_g(\text{Ric})=g^{ij}R_{ij}$.